# How to hide input fields for certain columns in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I want to hide the input fields for filtering Job and Age, like in the picture.

How can do that please I need help for my problem.

this my example
http://live.datatables.net/piqidoqo/610/edit

[image]

Comment: Do you want to hide them, or remove them?

Comment: Use `table.columns([1,2]).visible(false)` ...

Comment: @Steven I want to hide the input field for search 1,2 only and keep the data for job and age.

Comment: @davidkonrad thank you for help, but I want to hide the input field for search 1,2 only and keep the data for job and age.

Comment: Problem solved http://live.datatables.net/yaxusisi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
<td style="display:none">your html here</td>
```

along with

```
$('#your_table').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ column_number_you_want_to_hide ],
                "visible": false,
            },
          ]
});
```

Know that column numbers start from 0 and not 1.

Comment: Think you that help but, I want to hide the input field for search 1,2 only and keep the data for job and age.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with this code 
http://live.datatables.net/yaxusisi/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Create the DataTable
   var table = $("#example").DataTable({
     orderCellsTop: true,
    initComplete: function() {
    var table = this.api();

  // Add filtering
  table.columns([1,2]).every(function() {
    var that = this;

    // Create the `select` element
    var input = $('<input type="text" />')
      .appendTo($("thead tr:eq(1) td").eq(this.index()))
      .on("keyup", function() {
        that.search('^' + $(this).val() + '$', true, false).draw();
      });        
  });

  displaySearch();

}
 });
  });
```